# Symmetric proxy re-encryption practical implementations

Tags: implementation, proxy-re-encryption

I want to encrypt some files in a cloud and delegate decryption rights to authorized users. The performance matters for me and I think I should use schemes utilizing symmetric encryption.

Could anyone suggest practical (production ready, maybe) implementation for symmetric proxy re-encryption? I'm looking at pyUmbral, but this is thresholded scheme. I'm not sure if using it with **N=1** and **threshold=1** is ok (if it is, just let me know).

I also found "[Realizing proxy re-encryption in symmetric world](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265976071_Realizing_Proxy_Re-encryption_in_the_Symmetric_World)" paper, which looks promising for me, but I couldn't find any implementations.

Encrypting files with any symmetric cipher and proxy re-encrypt just decryption key is not ok for me, I want to be able to revoke access to files.

Thank you.

Comment: How much access will a legitimate user have to the decrypted file?  if they can copy/paste the information to their computer revocation won't help very much.

Comment: As soon as one user decrypted some file, he can download it and share with the others. Then nobody cares if you revoke permission for this file from any users. They will still have a copy of it. If you mean something other, please explain it better.

Comment: Your concerns about sharing already decrypted files are absolutely right! But the thing is the data is more like a database and will be updated (like adding new records). When I revoke access from the user he or she must not know the decryption key. E.g. if someone hacked the storage and downloaded encrypted data he or she can use decryption key obtained from the user with revoked access. That's what I mean :)